# Vue3 - How to use a custom ID in CSS url()?

Tags: css, url, vuejs3, clip-path

I have a vue component where I define an id for clipping `:id="'clipping_'+ UID"`. But when I try to use it in CSS `clip-path: url(v-bind("'#clipping_' + UID");`, it is seen as a var(), which is not allowed with url().

what would be the correct way to declare or access this id?
Thanks.

```
<template>
   <div>
      <svg class="svg">
         <clipPath
            :id="'clipping_'+ UID"
            clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <circle
               cx= "20"
               cy= "20"
               r="20"/>
         </clipPath>
      </svg>
      <div class="foreground"/>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default
   {
      name: 'myComponent',
      data: function ()
      {
         return {
            UID: "asdf",
         };
      }
   };
</script>

<style scoped>
   .foreground {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      background: hsl(356, 0%, 53%);

      clip-path: url(v-bind("'#clipping_' + UID");
      -webkit-clip-path: url(v-bind("'#clipping_' + UID");
   }

   .svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found that if url() can't have a var() in it, the opposite is possible.

```
clip-path: v-bind("'url(#clipping_' + UID + ')'");
```